# How to install Sql Server 2012 SP2 Cumlative update silently from installshield

Tags: sql-server, installshield, silent-installer, installshield-2014

We ship SQL Server 2012 express edition with our software package. Currently, we install SQL Server silently on client's machine. We needed to setup SQL server before Installer starts because of [Issue in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2820068). However, from 2012 SP2 Cumulative update 7, the issue is fixed. And now, we want to ship Sql Server 2012 SP2 Cumulative update 8 instead of SQL Server 2012.

We are not able to install cumulative update silently with the command that we used for Sql Server 2012.

Here is the command we use for silent installation of SQL Server 2012.

> sqlserver2012_x64.exe /Q /HIDECONSOLE /ACTION="Install" /UpdateEnabled=0 /FEATURES="SQL" /INSTANCENAME="Instance_Name" /SECURITYMODE="SQL" /SAPWD="PasswordforSA" /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS

Does anyone know if it is possible to install SQL Server cumulative updates silently like we do for Sql Server version from installshield?